# Unexpected behavior involving const_cast

Tags: c++, constants, stdstring, const-cast, copy-on-write

I came up with the following example, which exposes some unexpected behavior.
I would expect that after push_back, whatever is in the vector is there.
It looks like the compiler somehow decided to re-use memory used by str.

Could someone explain what is happening in this example? 
Is this valid c++ code?

The original problem arises from code responsible for serializing / deserializing messages and it uses const_cast to remove constness.
After noticing some unexpected behavior with that code, I created this simplified example, which tries to demonstrate the issue.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    auto str = std::string("XYZ"); // mutable string
    const auto& cstr(str);         // const ref to it

    vector<string> v;
    v.push_back(cstr);

    cout << v.front() << endl;  // XYZ is printed as expected

    *const_cast<char*>(&cstr[0])='*'; // this will modify the first element in the VECTOR (is this expected?)
    str[1]='#';  //

    cout << str << endl;  // prints *#Z as expected
    cout << cstr << endl; // prints *#Z as expected
    cout << v.front() << endl; // Why *YZ is printed, not XYZ and not *#Z ?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You sure? Prints XYZ for me like I'd expect - since you're not modifying `v`'s string...

Comment: https://ideone.com/5EnKAZ can't duplicate, however that is not what `const_cast` is for.

Comment: I used g++ 5.4.0 and clang++ 4.0.0. Both give the same result
~~~ 
    ~/tmp$ g++ -std=c++14  x.cpp
    ~/tmp$ ./a.out
    XYZ
    *#Z
    *#Z
    *YZ
~~~

Comment: clang 4.0: https://godbolt.org/z/SoNVEk  g++ 5.4: https://godbolt.org/z/rE73lI Still not happening.

Comment: For me the example prints 4 lines: 1 - XYZ, 2 - *#Z 3 - *#Z and the last line which is in question prints *YZ

Comment: I don't think there's an undefined behavior here. `const_cast` works as long as the data was not declared const. `std::string` does not store its data as const array as far as I know.

Comment: Reproduced here: https://onlinegdb.com/Hy78LVoTV

Comment: kudos for actually recreating the problem in a propper [MCVE]. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Understanding the bug

**The unexpected behavior occurs because of quirks in a depreciated implementation of `std::string`.** Older versions of GCC implemented `std::string` using *copy-on-write* semantics. It's a clever idea, but it causes bugs like the one you're seeing. What that means is that GCC tried to define `std::string` so that the internal string buffer only got copied if the new `std::string` was modified. For example:

```
std::string A = "Hello, world";
std::string B = A; // No copy occurs (yet)
A[3] = '*'; // Copy occurs now because A got modified.
```

When you take a constant pointer, however, no copy occurs because the library assumes that the string will not be modified through that pointer:

```
std::string A = "Hello, world"; 
std::string B = A;
std::string const& A_ref = A;

const_cast<char&>(A_ref[3]) = '*'; // No copy occurs (your bug)
```

As you've noticed, *copy-on-write* semantics tends to cause bugs. Because of this, and because copying a string is pretty cheap (all things considered), the copy *copy-on-write* implementation of `std::string` was **depreciated and removed** in GCC 5.

**So why are you seeing this bug if you're using GCC 5?** It's likely that you're compiling and linking an older version of the C++ standard library (one where copy-on-write is still the implementation of `std::string`). This is what's causing the bug for you.

**Check which version of the C++ standard library you're compiling against, and if possible, update your compiler.**

#### How can I tell which implemenation of `std::string` my compiler is using?

- New GCC implementation: `sizeof(std::string) == 32` (when compiling for 64 bit)
- Old GCC implementation: `sizeof(std::string) == 8` (when compiling for 64 bit)

If your compiler is using the old implementation of `std::string`, then `sizeof(std::string)` is the same as `sizeof(char*)` because `std::string` is implemented as a pointer to a block of memory. The block of memory is the one that actually contains things like the size and capacity of the string.

```
struct string { //Old data layout
    size_t* _data; 
    size_t size() const {
        return *(data - SIZE_OFFSET); 
    }
    size_t capacity() const {
        return *(data - CAPACITY_OFFSET); 
    }
    char const* data() const {
        return (char const*)_data; 
    }
};
```

On the other hand, if you're using the newer implementation of `std::string`, then `sizeof(std::string)` should be 32 bytes (on 64 bit systems). This is because the newer implementation stores the size and capacity of the string within the `std::string` itself, rather than in the data it points to:

```
struct string { // New data layout
    char* _data;
    size_t _size;
    size_t _capacity; 
    size_t _padding; 
    // ...
};
```

**What's good about the new implementation?** The new implementation has a number of benefits:

- Accessing size and capacity can be done more quickly (since the optimizer is more likely to store them in the registers, or at the very least they're likely to be in the cache)
- Because `std::string` is 32 bytes, we can take advantage of Small String Optimization. Small String Optimization allows strings less than 16 characters long to be stored within the space normally taken up by `_capacity` and `_padding`. This avoids heap allocations, and is faster for most use cases.

We can see below that GDB uses the old implementation of `std::string`, because `sizeof(std::string)` returns 8 bytes:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I also added a way to distinguish between the old implementation and the new implementation so you can tell which one's being used

Comment: I'm deeply convinced that COW string is a terribly flawed idea on many levels (in fact any clever optimization in a fundamental basic block and any simple class is a bad idea) but this is clearly cannot be a convincing argument. The fix for buggy code involving `const_cast` is to avoid the cast, respect const safety and also don't mess up with string data via a pointer.

Comment: COW behavior was depreciated and removed, and const_cast is a valid decision in certain situations. Updating the compiler will fix the COW behavior, and so I recommended it.